# Spring Mvc @InitBinder Validation

Tags: spring, validation, spring-mvc

I have a **Spring MVC** application and i have a Validation class that implements **Validator**. This validation class is called in the controller using the **@InitBinder** annotation. This validation occurs before inserting a record into the database however when i want to do an update i would not need all the fields to be validated from this validation class. I insert a record and update using the same view and the view has a controller that handles the insert and update based on **HttpRequest**.

Is there a way in the Validation class where i can specify the request the user makes so i wont validate the userName again since its an update.

Is it that i would have to pass in an Http Request to this class and then receive the user defined operation in the class and then use it to tweak my validation based on operation, if so how can it be done? I want to validate certain fields in the validation class based on the users request either and insert into th database or an update.

**Validation class**

```
public class OfficerRegistrationValidation implements Validator{


    private final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(getClass());

    @Autowired
    public ValidateUserManager validateUserManager;

    public boolean supports(Class<?> clazz) {

        return Officers.class.equals(clazz);
    }


    public void validate(Object target, Errors errors) {

        Officers officer = (Officers) target;



    if (officer.getUserName() == null){.......................
```

**Controller function that handles request**

```
 @RequestMapping(value="officer_registration.htm", method=RequestMethod.POST)
     public ModelAndView handleRequest(@Valid @ModelAttribute Officers officer, 
                                        BindingResult result,
                                        ModelMap m,
                                        Model model,
                                        HttpServletRequest request,
                                        HttpServletResponse response)throws Exception{

         try{
             if(result.hasErrors()){

                 model.addAttribute("division", myDivision);
                 model.addAttribute("position", myPosition);
                 model.addAttribute("gender", myGender);
                 return new ModelAndView("officer_registration");

            }else{

                //check the request if its an update or an insert
                String user_request = request.getParameter("user_request");
                logger.info("The Users Request Was " + user_request);

                if (user_request.equals("Save")){

                        officerManager.RegisterOfficer(officer);
                        model.addAttribute("badgeNoStatus","true");
                        model.addAttribute("saveBtnStatus","disabled");
                        model.addAttribute("userNameStatus","true");
                        model.addAttribute("startDateStatus","true");
                        model.addAttribute("icon","ui-icon ui-icon-circle-check");
                        model.addAttribute("results","Record Was Saved");

                }else{//if its an update
                    //only need certain validation from the validation class here 
                    officerManager.UpdateOfficer(officer);
```

.......................

**UPDATED 2012-10-18**

when i annotate the class with @Component and add @Autowired private HttpServletRequest request together with the getters and setters for this i am getting the following error:

**Error Log**

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource.close(BasicDataSource.java:486)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DisposableBeanAdapter.invokeCustomDestroyMethod(DisposableBeanAdapter.java:300)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DisposableBeanAdapter.destroy(DisposableBeanAdapter.java:226)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.destroyBean(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:498)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.destroySingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:474)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.destroySingletons(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:442)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.destroyBeans(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1066)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:472)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:385)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:284)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:111)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4705)
    at org.apache.catalina.manager.ManagerServlet.start(ManagerServlet.java:1276)
    at org.apache.catalina.manager.HTMLManagerServlet.start(HTMLManagerServlet.java:625)
    at org.apache.catalina.manager.HTMLManagerServlet.doGet(HTMLManagerServlet.java:136)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:617)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.filters.CsrfPreventionFilter.doFilter(CsrfPreventionFilter.java:186)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:563)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:293)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:859)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:602)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:489)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
1580 [http-8084-2] ERROR org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader  - Context initialization failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'officerRegistrationValidation' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Could not instantiate bean class [com.crimetrack.service.OfficerRegistrationValidation]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:997)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:943)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:485)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:294)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:225)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:585)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:913)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:464)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:385)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:284)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:111)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4705)
    at org.apache.catalina.manager.ManagerServlet.start(ManagerServlet.java:1276)
    at org.apache.catalina.manager.HTMLManagerServlet.start(HTMLManagerServlet.java:625)
    at org.apache.catalina.manager.HTMLManagerServlet.doGet(HTMLManagerServlet.java:136)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:617)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.filters.CsrfPreventionFilter.doFilter(CsrfPreventionFilter.java:186)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:563)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:293)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:859)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:602)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:489)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Could not instantiate bean class [com.crimetrack.service.OfficerRegistrationValidation]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:162)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:76)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:990)
    ... 36 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.crimetrack.service.OfficerRegistrationValidation.<init>(OfficerRegistrationValidation.java:30)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:147)
    ... 38 more
```

**Error Log after adding org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener**

```
850  [http-8084-2] DEBUG org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DisposableBeanAdapter  - Invoking destroy method 'close' on bean with name 'dataSource'
850  [http-8084-2] WARN  org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DisposableBeanAdapter  - Invocation of destroy method 'close' failed on bean with name 'dataSource'
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource.close(BasicDataSource.java:486)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DisposableBeanAdapter.invokeCustomDestroyMethod(DisposableBeanAdapter.java:300)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DisposableBeanAdapter.destroy(DisposableBeanAdapter.java:226)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.destroyBean(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:498)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.destroySingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:474)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.destroySingletons(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:442)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.destroyBeans(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1066)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:472)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:385)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:284)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:111)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4705)
    at org.apache.catalina.manager.ManagerServlet.start(ManagerServlet.java:1276)
    at org.apache.catalina.manager.HTMLManagerServlet.start(HTMLManagerServlet.java:625)
    at org.apache.catalina.manager.HTMLManagerServlet.doGet(HTMLManagerServlet.java:136)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:617)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.filters.CsrfPreventionFilter.doFilter(CsrfPreventionFilter.java:186)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:563)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:293)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:859)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:602)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:489)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
850  [http-8084-2] ERROR org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader  - Context initialization failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'officerRegistrationValidation' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Could not instantiate bean class [com.crimetrack.service.OfficerRegistrationValidation]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:997)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:943)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:485)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:294)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:225)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:585)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:913)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:464)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:385)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:284)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:111)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4705)
    at org.apache.catalina.manager.ManagerServlet.start(ManagerServlet.java:1276)
    at org.apache.catalina.manager.HTMLManagerServlet.start(HTMLManagerServlet.java:625)
    at org.apache.catalina.manager.HTMLManagerServlet.doGet(HTMLManagerServlet.java:136)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:617)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.filters.CsrfPreventionFilter.doFilter(CsrfPreventionFilter.java:186)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:563)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:293)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:859)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:602)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:489)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Could not instantiate bean class [com.crimetrack.service.OfficerRegistrationValidation]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:162)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:76)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:990)
    ... 36 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.crimetrack.service.OfficerRegistrationValidation.<init>(OfficerRegistrationValidation.java:31)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:147)
    ... 38 more
```

**ApplicationContext.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
         xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
         xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"

         xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop 
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.0.xsd
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx 
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.0.xsd
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd"> 

<!-- __________________________________________________________________________________________________ -->        

    <bean id="officerManager" class="com.crimetrack.service.OfficerManager">
        <property name ="officerDao" ref="officerDao"/>
    </bean>         
<!-- __________________________________________________________________________________________________ -->              

    <bean id="countryManager" class="com.crimetrack.service.CountryManager">
        <property name="countryDao" ref="countryDao"/>
    </bean>
    <bean id="countryDao" class="com.crimetrack.jdbc.JdbcCountryDAO">
        <constructor-arg index="0" ref="dataSource"/>
    </bean>
<!-- __________________________________________________________________________________________________ -->

    <bean id="authenticationManager" class="com.crimetrack.service.AuthenticationManager">
        <property name="loginDao" ref="loginDao" /> 
    </bean>    
    <bean id="loginDao" class="com.crimetrack.jdbc.JdbcLoginDAO">
         <constructor-arg index="0" ref="dataSource"/>
    </bean>
<!-- __________________________________________________________________________________________________ -->  

    <bean id="divisionManager" class="com.crimetrack.service.DivisionManager">
        <property name="divisionDao" ref="divisionDao"/>
    </bean>    
    <bean id="divisionDao" class="com.crimetrack.jdbc.JdbcDivisionDAO">
         <constructor-arg index="0" ref="dataSource"/>
    </bean>
<!-- __________________________________________________________________________________________________ -->    

     <bean id="positionManager" class="com.crimetrack.service.PositionManager">
        <property name="positionDao" ref="positionDao"/>
    </bean>    
    <bean id="positionDao" class="com.crimetrack.jdbc.JdbcPositionDAO">
         <constructor-arg index="0" ref="dataSource"/>
    </bean>      
<!-- __________________________________________________________________________________________________ -->    

    <bean id="genderManager" class="com.crimetrack.service.GenderManager">
        <property name="genderDao" ref="genderDao"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="genderDao" class="com.crimetrack.jdbc.JdbcGenderDAO" >
         <constructor-arg index="0" ref="dataSource"/>
    </bean> 
<!-- __________________________________________________________________________________________________ --> 

    <bean id="officerRegistrationValidation" class="com.crimetrack.service.OfficerRegistrationValidation">
        <property name="validateUserManager" ref="validateUserManager"/>            
    </bean>

    <bean id="validateUserManager" class="com.crimetrack.service.ValidateUserManager">
            <property name="officerDao" ref="officerDao"/>
    </bean>


    <bean id="officerDao" class="com.crimetrack.jdbc.JdbcOfficersDAO" >
            <constructor-arg index="0" ref="dataSource"/>
    </bean>         
<!-- __________________________________________________________________________________________________ --> 

    <bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource" destroy-method="close">
            <property name="driverClassName" value="${jdbc.driverClassName}"/>
            <property name="url" value="${jdbc.url}"/>
            <property name="username" value="${jdbc.username}"/>
            <property name="password" value="${jdbc.password}"/>
    </bean>
<!-- __________________________________________________________________________________________________ -->    

    <bean id="propertyConfigurer" 
          class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
        <property name="locations">
            <list>
                <value>classpath:jdbc.properties</value>
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>
<!-- __________________________________________________________________________________________________ -->    

    <bean id="transactionManager" 
          class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
    </bean>





  </beans>
```

Comment: I don't known how to do this with old validators, but with modern JSR-303 validators you may use groups and validate only desired groups with `@Validated`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i think if you mark you validator as `@Component` then you might be able to inject HttpRequest object to you validator bean by using below code

```
private @Autowired HttpServletRequest request;
```

Comment: The validator is is annotated '@Service' using the '@Component' results in errors

Comment: ok i can do the annotation to \@Component however when i add the private /@Autowired HttpServletRequest request and create the getters and setters for this i am getting Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Could not instantiate bean class com.crimetrack.service.OfficerRegistrationValidation]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException

Comment: you will need to enable listner to use request scope bean    <listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextListener</listener-class>
  </listener>

Comment: refer bean scope section in http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.0.M3/reference/html/ch04s04.html

Comment: @dev_darin i feel this error due to some other configuration as there is no data access code within validator, can you post complete code and spring configuration file

Comment: Updated added the ApplicationContext.xml